# Android: Pulling variable from one activity to another and set a textview.

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pull in a variable from one activity intent into another activity and set a textview with it. Here is some code:

```
//First Activity
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, showID.class);
    i.putExtra(HDWDBHelper.KEY_ROWID, id);
    myId = String.valueOf(id);
    i.putExtra(myId, id);
    Log.v("ID: ", myId);

    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SHOW);


}

//Second Activity

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showid);

    idNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();
    Long id = b.getLong("id");
    String myId = String.valueOf(id);
    Log.v("ShowID: ", myId);
    idNumber.setText(myId.toString());

}
```

I can not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you using `HDWDBHelper.KEY_ROWID` as the key passed to `getLong()` in the second Activity?

Comment: I tried to use that and still had same results after doing some research I tried this way and still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass primitive data from one activity to another as follows.

Define constant which will be used as Key to pass data.

```
public static final String EXTRA_YOUR_KEY = "EXTRA_YOUR_KEY";
```

Add the value as key-pair to the `Intent` which you are using to start new activity.

```
// code snippet for first activity
long myId = 10;
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(activity-context, ClassNameOfNewActivity.class);
activityIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_YOUR_KEY, myId);
startActivity(activityIntent);
```

Next, in the `onCreate()` of new activity, extract the passed value as

```
// code snippet from second activity's onCreate method
Intent intent = getIntent();
long id = intent.getLongExtra(ClassNameWhichContains.EXTRA_YOUR_KEY, 0);
```

I have used `long` as example since you are trying to pass in a `long` variable. Similarly, you can work out the other primitives.

And for passing custom objects between two activities you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1237297).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help, I used singh.jagmohan's example and got it to work.

Comment: @GarlingBeard : One thing I will say is don't put the `static final` key in a class which extends `Activity`. Create a separate class for constants and/or any static methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
myId = String.valueOf(id);
    i.putExtra(myId, id);
```

You're using the id value as key.

```
myId = "id";
```

that should work

edit*: if what you want is to pass a string, then

```
myId = String.valueOf(id);
    i.putExtra(myId, "id");
```

and then receive it

```
String myId = b.getString("id");
```

Comment: I am trying to convert the value of "id" to a string before it gets passed.

Comment: i put some more code, if i understand correctly you want to simply pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the extras are actually key value pairs and thus when inserting into extras you have to use "key" which is known to receiving side to be able to pull that value from the bundle by that name. Unfortunately the key could be anything even what you have used thare but that value is not what you know on receiver side. Try this-

Sending side:

```
i.putExtra("id", id);
```

Receiving side:

```
Long id = b.getLong("id");
```